# No such file or directory error when installing python package compound-split

Tags: python, azure

**Infrastructure and/or software involved:** Azure Cloud, Linux Machine and Python 3.9

**Objective:** Deployment of an Azure Function (Built in Python) through Terraform script and Azure cloud shell

**Context:** I created a Terraform script which I will execute on Azure cloud shell in order to deploy an Azure Function in the Cloud. The script installs all the python packages I need to that Function. I am facing a problem with the installation of the package called [compound-split](https://pypi.org/project/compound-split/). I am getting the following error:

No such file or directory

when the script runs the following command:

```
pip3 install -r compound-split==1.0.2 --target="${SCRIPT_DIR}/build/.python_packages/lib/site-packages"
```

I found the current Linux machine has only installed the python version 3.7.

**Question:** Anyone knows what this problem is about?. Any suggestions how should I install this package in that machine?

Tks in advance and forgive me if I explained something incorrectly.

**UPDATE 1:**

The complete error is:

> ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: 'compound-split==1.0.2'

I checked the version of the pip installed and I got the following result in the cloud shell:

> pip3 --version

> pip 22.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

**UPDATE 2:**

After changing what @Mime said, I got now another error:

> Killed   pip3 install compound-split==1.0.2
> --target="${SCRIPT_DIR}/build/.python_packages/lib/site-packages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the command in a false way.
The option `-r` specifies the use of a requirements file.
You may want to use the command without the `-r` option to install the package directly, rather than from a requirements file.

```
pip3 install compound-split==1.0.2 --target="${SCRIPT_DIR}/build/.python_packages/lib/site-packages"
```

For more information see the options section of the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/python3-pip/pip3.1.en.html)

Comment: Tks for your support. I tried python -m pip and also python3 -m pip and I got the same error. I updated the question with the exact error and also the current version of pip installed in that machine. Maybe the problem would be when we want to download the package from the source.

Comment: @sergioMoreno updated the answer, hopefully it will resolve the problem. For the next time, always copy the full error message, as that helps to determine the problem

Comment: Tks for your help again. Now I got another error. The error is "Killed". I have found it is a problem with the cache of the machine. I already used --no-cache-dir but still I got the same error "Killed". Have you any idea what could be the reason?.